# Converting dxf to shp and keep elevation information QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, dxf

I want to create a QGIS plugin that convert dxf files to shp. I didn't use DXF2SHP plugin in QGIS because I have some specific needs. I'm using gdal_ogr library.

```
dxfdat="*.dxf"
shpLinestring="*.shp"

opt1="-skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES FALSE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -gcp  z  -nlt LINESTRING "
sql1= "-sql \"SELECT *,ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY LIKE '%LINESTRING%'\" "
processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat',dxfdat , 0,opt1 + sql1, shpLinestring)
```

I can make the convertion but is it possible to keep the elevation attribute from dxf file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DXF is real 3D (Z-value not attribute)?
Then test the following:

> -**dim val**:(starting with GDAL 1.10) Force the coordinate dimension to val (valid values are XY, XYZ, XYM, and XYZM - for backwards
>   compatibility 2 is an alias for XY and 3 is an alias for XYZ). This
>   affects both the layer geometry type, and feature geometries. Starting
>   with GDAL 1.11, the value can be set to "layer_dim" to instruct
>   feature geometries to be promoted to the coordinate dimension declared
>   by the layer. Support for M was added in GDAL 2.1

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat',dxfdat , 0,sql1 + opt1 + ' -dim XYZ', shpLinestring)
```

A polyline usually has different z-values. As an attribute, you can only put one Z value for the entire line.
If that's enough for you, create a new field in the field calculator:[image]

---

Another way with SQLite-Synax:
Write the z-Value from the first point of LineString to Attribut

```
import processing
dxfdat="d:/tar/3d.dxf"
shpLinestring="d:/tar/1.shp"

opt1="-skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES FALSE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE -dim XYZ  -nlt LINESTRING "
sql1= "-dialect sqlite -sql \"SELECT *,ST_Z(ST_StartPoint (geometry)) as elevation, ogr_style from entities where GeometryType(geometry) LIKE '%LINESTRING%'\" "
processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat',dxfdat , 0,opt1 + sql1, shpLinestring)
```

Comment: thank u for the replay ! I found this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199479/exporting-contour-lines-from-cad-to-gis , and thanks to ur answer I can keep elevation (step 2) but how to add it as a field in the output layer ?

Comment: I added my answer

Comment: I need to code that, I've tried to use field calculator using : processing.runalg('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', shpLinestring, 'elevation', QVariant.Double, 10, 2, '',' z(point_n($geometry, 1))', shpLinestring) but it's not working

Comment: I added my answer

Comment: it doesn't work for me, may be because i'm using postgresql ?

Comment: "postgresql": I do not understand you now.
My code converts a DXF into a shape. This code can be started in the QGIS Python console.
"it doesn't work for me": Which error in which line.

Comment: I wanted to use postgresql syntax because I'm using postgresql driver in almost all plugins that i've created but I think it's okey to use sqlite driver.
Thank you !