# Contour lines from AutoCAD to QGIS: how to automatically assign the right value to the Z

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, spatial-join, elevation, autocad

I have a plate of contour lines made on AutoCAD (contour lines do not have a Z). The Z is indicated only for some curves but in a text format.
If you import the table in QGIS the situation is this (the points correspond to where the Z is indicated):

[image]

[image]

My question is: knowing that the contour lines shown are every 20 meters is there a way to automatically assign the right value to each curve having only this little information?
I thought about merging attributes between the layer of the contourlines and the text layer, but this would solve the situation for only a few curves.

Comment: Well, let me state it this way: No. This is tedious, manual work. I suggest you go back another step and think about creating the contour line in QGIS right away, ideally by automated conversion based on a DEM.

Comment: Have you seen this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199479/exporting-contour-lines-from-cad-to-gis ?

Comment: @Erik Unfortunately, these contour lines were taken from an Iranian relief. They are boards from I don't know how many years ago and I don't think that by downloading a DEM from the internet I would be able to get the same result, but I don't think I have any other option left...

Comment: @Taras No i hadn't seen this solution! thanks for pointing it out to me, now I'll try and see if it's right for me